# How to remove the Breadcrumbs from the homepage

Tags: magento-enterprise, cache, frontend, full-page-cache, programming

When Full Page Cache is on the breadcrumbs show up on the home page,

i've tried changing the line `<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>` to `<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs) && !$this->getIsHomePage()): ?>` in \app\design\frontend\enterprise\[THEME]\template\page\html\breadcrumbs.phtml yet it still shows up

i've tried adding `<remove name="breadcrumbs" />` to the "Layout Update XML" of the CMS page which is the homepage yet it still shows up

I've tried putting in `Mage::log()` or a `<p>` before the if statement however it works on every other page but the home page

a google search gives me nothing that i don't know (the Layout Update XML thing i got from one site) and most results are asking how to add the breadcrumbs when i search for "how to remove breadcrumbs from homepage

i'm wondering if there is any other way to remove the breadcrumbs from the homepage which i may have yet tried

Comment: Have you tried to `<remove name="breadcrumbs"/>` from `cms_index_index\root` of your `local.xml`?

Comment: @Tim is this `local.xml` file the one located in app/etc cause i look in there and i can't find anything relating to `cms_index_index\root` in there and there's no such file located in any of the layout folders in app/design/frontend

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=magento+local.xml&aq=0&oq=magento+local.&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62l2.4481&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What Tim means is your `local.xml` file inside your template directory like `/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/layout`

If the file does not exist, create it with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

This should work. Also refresh cashes.

Comment: yep, that seems to be working now, thanks

Comment: I have just had the same problem, this solution worked, but my question is what did you do to find out you need to target the <cms_index_index> node?

Comment: every action method has a default layout handle associated to it. the action which renders the store homepage is inside the indexcontroller of the mage_cms module. see `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php`-> indexAction(). the handle basically is <frontname_controllername_actionname>. magento also adds a class to your <body ..> tag corresponding to that handle (cms-index-index). so the easiest way to find the node for a particular page would be to view the page source in your browser and look at the associated body class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove breadcrumbs on every CMS Pages, try removing from System-->Web-->Default Pages-->Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages

Comment: i didn't know about that option, however since we have CMS pages for other sections and we want breadcrumbs for them changing that option will affect more than just the homepage but it's useful to know about it

Answer (score 0):

[Magento Add Breadcrumbs For CMS Page](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/05/magento-add-breadcrumbs-for-cms-page.html) check this link
you can add in single cms page Breadcrumbs follow below code.

you can added this code in you cms page. edit your cmspage ->design->Layout Update XML->

```
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/category.phtml</template></action>
 <action method="unsetChild"><alias>breadcrumbs</alias></action>    
    <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>About us</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>SHOP</label><title>SHOP</title></crumbInfo>
        </action>      
    </block>
</reference>
```

this code for breadcrumbs my page name is shop add title shop and also change label shop

```
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>breadcrumbs</alias></action>    
    <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>About us</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>SHOP</label><title>SHOP</title></crumbInfo>
        </action>      
    </block>
```

I think you can help this code.